# Rails API path in browser gives this error NoMethodError undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I have created a Rails API and when I run either this path http://localhost:3000/api/v1/records or http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items in the browser address bar, I get the error as displayed in the image below
[image]

Below is the entire code in the application_controller.rb file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  SECRET_KEY = Rails.application.credentials.jwt[:secret].to_s
  EXPIRES_IN = Rails.application.credentials.jwt[:expires_in]

  def authorized
    render json: {message: 'Please log in'}, status: 401 unless logged_in?
  end

  def encode_token(payload)
    payload[:exp] = EXPIRES_IN.days.from_now.to_i
    JWT.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, 'HS256')
  end

  def auth_header
    return unless request.headers['Authorization']
    request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1]
  end

  def decoded_token
    return unless auth_header

    token = auth_header
    begin
      JWT.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, true, algorithm: 'HS256')
    rescue JWT::DecodeError
      nil
    end
  end

  def logged_in_user
    return unless decoded_token

    user_id = decoded_token[0]['user_id']
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
  end

  def logged_in?
    logged_in_user ? true : false
  end
end
```

Any help on how I can fix this will be greatly appreciated. This is the first Rails API I am building.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually very precise. It tells you that there is no method `[]` defined on `nil` and it tells you where ther error is happening: in the second line of the ApplicationController.

The second line of that controller looks like this:

```
SECRET_KEY = Rails.application.credentials.jwt[:secret].to_s
```

That means if Rails compains about calling `[]` on a `nil` value then

```
Rails.application.credentials.jwt
```

must return `nil`.

It looks like you haven't setup the secret credentials correctly or the format of the file is somehow broken.

I suggest reading about [Custom Credentials](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security) in the Rails Guides.